# Accessing self in NSBlockOperation – retain cycle?

Tags: objective-c

```
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self doSomethingElse];        
}];

- (void)doSomethingElse {
    [self doAnother];
}
```

Does this create a retain cycle? I keep a reference to the operation queue but not the operation. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could create a retain cycle. Create a weak pointer to self and use that:

```
_weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
```

EDIT:

In your block, create a strong reference back to self. Evaluate your pointer to make sure it's valid, and you're safe. Your snippet (based on what you've described, then), should read:

```
self.opeartionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
_weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
[[self operationQueue] addOperationBlock:^{

    _strong MyObject *strongSelf = weakSelf; // Obtain a strong reference so our pointer won't dangle out from under us...

    if(strongSelf) // Make sure it's valid
    {
        [strongSelf doSomethingElse]; // Do your work
    }
}
```

Comment: What about in `doSomethingElse`? Would I have to pass the weak reference there as well in order to call `doAnother`?

Comment: And then be sure to call `cancelAllOperations` in self's `dealloc`.

Comment: @isaac That answer is only half the story. Before the block, he should say `_weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;` But first thing inside the block, he should say `MyObject* strongSelf = self;` and he should refer only to `strongSelf` from then on. Why? This is a thread, and `weakSelf` is weak, so self could go out of existence in the middle of the operation. This way, if self survives into the start of the block, it is retained and stays alive just for as long as the block executes.

Comment: But you guys don't follow. Even if I use a weak reference to self when I call `doSomething`, don't I incur a retain cycle in the other method where I call self?

Comment: You do not. In the other method `self` is an argument.

Comment: @matt You are correct, I've extended the original answer per your comment.